# How to get Netbeans GUI Builder to not auto-generate fully qualified class names for components

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, gui-builder

how can i use shorter code like eclipse in netbeans  while using GUI Builder?
for example

```
Jbutton btnCalculate = new javax.swing.JButton();
```

is generated automatically but i want shorter code like in eclipse

```
Jbutton btnCalculate = new JButton();
```

While creating a button !

Comment: I don't think this is a bad question. Just poorly worded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "how can i use shorter code like eclipse in netbeans while using swing designer? "

1. Go to **Tools -> Options**
2. Click **Java** Button
3. Click **GUI Builder** tab
4. De-select **Generate Fully Qualified Name of Classes**

As you Drag and Drop components, imports will be added for you.

Also, if you want to hand code a component that has not been imported yet, just hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to resolve all imports.

> There is also a per-form option: select the root node in Inspector window and see Generate Full Classnames property in Properties window.

Comment: thanks @peterSmith it worked ! and the changes will work for only on new GUI elements created !

Answer (score 2):

Import your resources.

```
import javax.swing.*;
```

And note that in the second example, `btnCalculate` is never declared, like in the first.

Comment: yea i got it ! automated generator generated codes like in first code ! and i tried to add import line but it says unused import!